# Displaying model data in _LogonPartial

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm using ASP MVC3 from the new project template which gives me _Layout.cshtml and _LogOnPartial.cshtml. In the _LogOnPartial there is the text that is displayed when a user logs in. How do I display my own additional data there from my model and have it displayed across all views?

Here's what I tried but of course it doesn't work because there is no model data:

```
@if(Request.IsAuthenticated) {
<text>Hello, <strong>@User.Identity.Name</strong>! - Account Balance: @Model.GetAccountBalance()
[ @Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOff", "Account") ]</text>
}
else {
@:[ @Html.ActionLink("Log On", "LogOn", "Account") ]
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have something similar and use the Html.RenderAction() to actually display the account information box.  Basically, it would be a pretty simple setup

**Layout View**

```
@{Html.RenderAction("Information", "Account");}
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class AccountInformation(){
    public bool IsAuthenticated {get;set;}
    public string UserName {get;set;}
    public int AccountBalance {get;set;}
}
```

**Account Controller**

```
public PartialViewResult Information(){
   var model = new AccountInformation();
   model.IsAutenticated = httpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
   if(model.IsAuthenticated){
       model.UserName = httpContext.User.Identity.Name;
       model.AccountBalance = functionToGetAccountBalance();
       //Return the fully populated ViewModel
       return this.PartialView(model);
   }
   //return the model with IsAuthenticated only set since none of the 
   //other properties are needed
   return this.ParitalView(model);
}
```

**Information View**

```
@model AccountInformation

@if(Model.IsAuthenticated) {
<text>Hello, <strong>@Model.UserName</strong>! - Account Balance: @Model.AccountBalance
[ @Html.ActionLink("Log Off", "LogOff", "Account") ]</text>
}
else {
@:[ @Html.ActionLink("Log On", "LogOn", "Account") ]
}
```

This does a few things and brings in some options

1. Keeps your view from having to sniff around the HttpContext.  Let the controller deal with that.
2. You can now combine this with an [OutputCache] attribute so you are not having to render it Every. Single. Page.
3. If you need to add more stuff to the Account Information screen, it is as simple as updating the ViewModel and populating the data.  No magic, no ViewBag, etc.

Answer (score -2):

You have to modify the ViewModel used on this View and add your additional data to it.